# Redirect subprocess.run output to file

Tags: python, grep, subprocess, output

I've seen a lot of other pages here that talk output grep output to a file but I can't seem to make any of those work.

I have

```
subprocess.run(['grep', '-o', searchFor, filename])
```

if this wasn't a subprocess I would use something like

```
grep -o searchfor filename >> outputfile.txt
```

and when I try to use `>` or `>>` or anything else in the subprocess, I can't get it to output to a simple txt file. I assume that this is because most all of the pages I've seen here are writing to a file from *regular command compared to me trying within the subprocess*. My guess is that my syntax is wrong. Where should `>` or `>>` or whatever I should be using go? I've tried after the `]` and before and many other combinations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the file in write (`>`) or append (`>>`) mode, and assign the descriptor associated with it to `stdout` in `subprocess.run` call.

```
with open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as fd:
  subprocess.run(['grep', '-o', searchFor, filename], stdout=fd)
```